# Rails: Not receiving email from contact us form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a app in hosted in heroku just to test if the contact us form work but never receive a email, this is my contact model

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :message
  attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

  # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
  # in ActionMailer accepts.
  def headers
    {
      :subject => "My Contact Form",
      :to => "contact@gmail.com",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

and thid my production.rb file

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'young-river-2391.herokuapp.com' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            'contact@gmail.com',
    password:             'mypassword',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

Update:
This is what I'm getting from the console

```
2014-11-08T17:35:07.141130+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/contacts" for 105.132.166.163 at 2014-11-08 17:35:07 +0000
2014-11-08T17:35:07.142447+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
2014-11-08T17:35:07.142452+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
2014-11-08T17:35:07.142497+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"t152NgJZxX9mIdlRS/CGsxH6lCwg3PDj0UphBnHXOZw=", "contact"=>{"name"=>"name ", "email"=>"name@gmail.com", "message"=>"This is a message", "nickname"=>""}, "commit"=>"Send message"}
2014-11-08T17:35:07.142513+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"t152NgJZxX9mIdlRS/CGsxH6lCwg3PDj0UphBnHXOZw=", "contact"=>{"name"=>"name ", "email"=>"name@gmail.com", "message"=>"This is a message", "nickname"=>""}, "commit"=>"Send message"}
2014-11-08T17:35:07.149561+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mail_form-1.5.0/lib/mail_form/views/mail_form/contact.erb (0.7ms)
2014-11-08T17:35:07.149568+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mail_form-1.5.0/lib/mail_form/views/mail_form/contact.erb (0.7ms)
2014-11-08T17:35:07.141175+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/contacts" for 105.132.166.163 at 2014-11-08 17:35:07 +0000
2014-11-08T17:35:07.417088+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/contacts" host=young-river-2391.herokuapp.com request_id=7cabe546-1435-4626-a441-01377a668def fwd="105.132.166.163" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=281ms status=200 bytes=1719
2014-11-08T17:35:07.414677+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-11-08T17:35:07.414680+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to contact@gmail.com (263.7ms)
2014-11-08T17:35:07.414686+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-11-08T17:35:07.414687+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to contact@gmail.com (263.7ms)
2014-11-08T17:35:07.415701+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered contacts/create.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
2014-11-08T17:35:07.415706+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered contacts/create.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
2014-11-08T17:35:07.416507+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 274ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-11-08T17:35:07.416512+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 274ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: what does the `log` say?

Comment: I'm trying this in production and it appear like teh message is sent but i don't receive anything check the app plz https://young-river-2391.herokuapp.com/contacts

Comment: can't sort out from html. try `heroku logs --tail` from console.

Comment: have you tried to login in your gmail account?

Comment: Yes a have login to my gmail account

Comment: look at update to see what i'm getting from consol

Comment: Is it working in your development machine? You may find the [letter_opener_web](https://github.com/fgrehm/letter_opener_web) gem useful

Answer (score 0):

Did you add SendGrid or one of the other mail add-ons? These are required to send email from your heroku App.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp

Comment: You don't need to use an add-on. Solely with Gmail should be working.